# Sql Query With GroupBys - Impossible Query

Tags: sql

I have the following:

```
Name    Age When
Paul    21  01-Jan-10
Paul    54  01-Jan-11
Paul    65  01-Jan-12
```

I want to pull out all names and that age wherer the date is >= 01-Jan-11

I ve tried

```
SELECT NAME, AGE, MIN(When)
FROM ATABLE
WHERE When >= '01-Jan-11'
GROUP BY NAME, AGE
```

That did not work - I get the 01 Jan 2011 AND 01 Jan 2012 for Paul which is wrong - I just want the one

NOTE: This comment is the most correct so far but does not provide an answer :(

You're where clause will get 2 records and will keep them as 2 records since you're grouping by Name and Age. If Name and Age were the same, it'd be 1 record and not 2.

Comment: "That did not work" isn't terribly informative. Could you explain what happened? Also, I can't see where C# comes into this question.

Comment: Please post the resultset you'd like to get.

Comment: What's the data type on [WHEN]? Are you actually using the aggregate or is that just an idea you were trying? The question sounds like you only want Name/Age.

Comment: Is this just a matter of `>` vs `>=`?  Also, I'm failing to see why a group by is necessary...

Comment: You're where clause will get 2 records and will keep them as 2 records since you're grouping by Name and Age.  If Name and Age were the same, it'd be 1 record and not 2.

Comment: Also, what DBMS are you using? Earlier I had assumed SQL Server since you mentioned C# but that is not necessarily the case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHEN` is a SQL Server reserved word - if that is really your column name it might be causing you problems. In any case, it would be helpful to post more information, such as any errors you were receiving.

Also for what its worth, normally I would use `DATEDIFF` for the date comparison:

```
  SELECT NAME, AGE, MIN(When)
    FROM ATABLE
   WHERE DATEDIFF ( 'd', '2001-01-01', When ) > 0
GROUP BY NAME, AGE
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT NAME, AGE, MIN(When) FROM A TABLE WHERE When >= '2011/01/01' GROUP BY NAME, AG
```

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/2209321/Working-with-SQL-Server-DateTime-Variables-Part-Three---Searching-for-Particular-Date-Values-and-Ranges.htm

Comment: This is assuming it is a real date time, as sql has no way of figuring out a range of dates based on a string

Answer (score 0):

In `SQL Server`:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT name
        FROM    atable
        ) ad
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 *
        FROM    atable ai
        WHERE   ai.name = ad.name
                AND When >= '01-Jan-11'
        ORDER BY
                When
        ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

thats easy...

```
SELECT NAME, AGE, MIN(When)
FROM ATABLE
WHERE 
    YEAR([When]) >= 2011
    AND MONTH([When]) >= 1
    AND DAY([When]) >= 1
GROUP BY NAME, AGE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  k.Name, t.Age, k.MinWhen
FROM    (
        SELECT  Name, MIN(When) MinWhen
        FROM    ATABLE
        GROUP BY Name
        ) k
        JOIN ATABLE t ON
            t.Name = k.Name
        AND t.When = k.MinWhen
```